# Openmp: How to collect an array from different threads?

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, fortran, openmp

I am a OpenMP newbie and I am stuck at a problem! I have an array which is summed in a loop but I am having problems parallelizing this. Can you suggest how to do this? The main loop is sketched as follows:

```
      REAL A (N)   ! N is an integer

      !$OMP PARALLEL
      DO I=1,10   ! just an illustration
        DO J=1,10  ! can't post real code sorry, illegal

          !$OMP DO
          DO K=1,100
            call messy_subroutine_that_sums_A(I,J, K, A) ! each thread returns its own sum
            ! each thread returns its own A right? and needs to summed quickly
          END DO
          !$OMP END DO

       END DO
     END DO


     SUBROUTINE messy_subroutine_that_sums_A(I,J, K, A)
       REAL A(N) ! an array
       ! basically adds some stuff to the previous value of A

       A=A+junk ! this is really junk
     END SUBROUTINE messy_subroutine_that_sums_A
```

my problem is that all my attempts to collect `A` from all the threads have failed. If you notice `A` is summed over outer loops as well. What is the correct and a fast procedure to collect `A` from all the arrays as a sum. Secondly, my question is not just a Fortran question, it applies equally to C and C++. It is a conceptual question.

Comment: You might be trying to perform *array reduction in OpenMP* even searching here on SO will turn up some Qs and As.  Lucky for you that you chose Fortran, OpenMP does not support reductions on arrays in C or C++ -- you have to write your own code in those languages.

Comment: Does reduction work on an array? I tried that earlier and the code just hung doing nothing. What does that mean?

Comment: Yes, OpenMP can perform reduction on arrays using Fortran.  Hit your search engine, I don't have time to write an answer -- which is why I'm just writing comments.

Comment: I don't know if you actually solved this yet, but furthermore, you need to ensure that your element k is private to each thread by using `!$omp parallel private(k)`. Otherwise your answer will still be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually OpenMP does support reduction on arrays in C, C++ (declared recently in OpenMP 4.1 comment draft release), and of cause in Fortran.

Not all implementations may support this feature, so you would better first check if you compiler supports it. To see if you have correct calculations you can start with placing `A=A+junk` into critical section:

```
!$omp critical
  A=A+junk
!$omp end critical
```

This should give you same correct answer in all threads after the OMP DO loop.

Then you can optimize performance using array reduction instead of `critical` on OMP DO loop, again having same correct answer in all threads after the loop.

Then you can further optimize performance moving the reduction to OMP PARALLEL, but you won't be able to check values in all threads in this case, because all threads will work with private copies of the array A, and thus have different partial values. Final correct answer will be available in master thread only, after the OMP PARALLEL.

Note, you don't need to declare loop iteration variables private in Fortran, as they should be automatically made private.